# Clickhouse aggregate page view user flow by sessions

Tags: sql, database, statistics, analytics, clickhouse

The clickhouse database table looks somewhat like this:

| Timestamp | SessionId | PagePath | ReferrerPath | ... |

My desired outcome would be something along these lines in order to visualize the page flow of sessions in a sankey diagram (SQL query is based on each step of next navigation):

| PagePath | ReferrerPath | Count |

The following SQL achieves this but it does not make sure that they are unique routes of sessions:

```
SELECT p.PagePath AS url, p.ReferrerPath AS referrer, COUNT(*) as count
FROM analytics.page_view_buffer p
WHERE 
    p.ReferrerPath = '/' OR p.ReferrerPath = '/websites' OR p.ReferrerPath = '/project'
GROUP BY p.PagePath, p.ReferrerPath
```

Problems with this query:

- It does not take into account to acknowledge the route

The above point means that for example / -> /home -> / flow would mean that the query for the third point would return the same amount for /home again but this would be wrong because the route is more specific on third step than first step.

- It does not limit the amount of returned results

This means if it is possible, it would be good to limit the result to 5 for example and have the rest be summed together as "rest" or similiar

Does someone have an idea how to modify the above query to fix the 2 mentioned problems?

As visual guidance here is an example from google analytics on what i wanna achieve later with the query:
[image]